# Passing Argument from Batch File to Python

Tags: python, batch-file, exception, null, arguments

I am trying to pass argument from batch file to python as following. It seems nothing has passed to 'sample' variable. My questions are

1. How to get argument properly?
2. How to check null point error when I am running .bat to execute this python? I may not be able to see the console log in IDE while executing

My batch file (.bat)

```
start python test.py sample.xml
```

My python file (test.py)

```
def main(argv):
    sample = argv[1]   #How to get argument here?
    tree = ET.parse(sample)
    tree.write("output.xml")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you're skipping the first argument **twice**.

`main` gets called with `sys.argv[1:]`, skipping the first argument (program name); but then `main` itself uses `argv[1]`... skipping **its** first argument again.

Just pass `sys.argv` untouched to `main` and you'll be fine, for example.

Or, perhaps more elegantly, do call `main(sys.argv[1:])`, but then, in `main`, use `argv[0]`!

Answer (score 1):

Use argparse https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Eg: In your python file

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Your prog description.')
parser.add_argument('-f','--foo', help='Description for foo argument', required=True)
    :
    :
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Inside your bat file

```
python prog.py -f <foo arg here>
```

Comment: optparse is deprecated; you should prefer using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) now.

Comment: Updated myself and answer to argparse, Thanks