# Unable to pass argument from batch file to python file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, python-2.x

I am trying to pass an argument from batch file to my python file.
I followed the steps given in these two links:

- [Passing Argument from Batch File to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810974/passing-argument-from-batch-file-to-python)
- [Sending arguments from Batch file to Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823033/sending-arguments-from-batch-file-to-python-script)

Here is a part of my python file where I'm trying to pass argument:

```
def main(argv):
imapServ = 'imap.gmail.com'
filename = 'TestRunLog.log'
attachment = open("{} {}".format(argv[0], filename), 'rb')
....##rest of the code

import sys
try:
if __name__ == '__main__':
   print 'go ahead'
   main(sys.argv[:1])
except ImportError:
   print 'hi'
```

Also, here is the part of batch file which I'm using to send argument to the Python file:

```
c:\python27\python.exe C:\Users\abcd\Documents\automation\testsendemail.py %%myhome%\Documents\automation\Testresults\%resultDir%
pause
```

Above, `%resultDir%` is the variable which is generated based on timestamp.

Here is the output:

```
go ahead
Traceback (most recent call last):
C:/Users/abcd/Documents/automation/testsendemail.py\TestRunLog.log
  File "C:/Users/abcd/Documents/automation/testsendemail.py", line 44, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[:1])
  File "C:/Users/abcd/Documents/automation/testsendemail.py", line 25, in main
    attachment = open("{} {}".format(argv[0], filename), 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/abcd/Documents/automation/testsendemail.py TestRunLog.log'
```

I followed lots of stackoverflow questions regarding this issue but still I'm unable to run. Not sure where the mistake is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is related on how python works with argv.
In this scenario, when you run:

```
main(sys.argv[:1]) # (["C:\Users\abcd\Documents\automation\testsendemail.py"])
```

you actually get **only** the first arguments passed to the python script, which is the current script location.

To get all the arguments but the first, you must fix that array filter:

```
main(sys.argv[1:]) # ["%%myhome%\Documents\automation\Testresults\%resultDir%"])
```

Note that the second filter will also include any other arguments that you might add to the command line.

---

Also, as a side note. You should consider using the STD lib to join the paths.
It should be something like this:

```
from os.path import join
(...)
filename = 'TestRunLog.log'
attachment = open(join(argv[0], filename), 'rb')
```